# Which one is more friendly to developers and SMBs: DigitalOcean or Linode?

Tags: server, cloud, digital-ocean, linode

Both the DigitalOcean and Linode are popular among developers and SMBs, but which one provides better experience for developers & SMBs and earns better reputation? DigitalOcean seems to have a higher market share, yet Linode scored better in G2 IaaS providers list.